# How to use Auto correction, Text Replace or Abbreviation in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rngCell As Range

For Each rngCell In Range("A2:A11")

If rngCell.Value = "EC" Then rngCell.Value = "EGG CURRY"
If rngCell.Value = "FC" Then rngCell.Value = "FISH CURRY"

Next

End Sub
```

This is a good example I found on Internet.
But I need Cell Reference from another sheet, where in One Column I want to write "EC", "FC" etc and another column I want to write "EGG CURRY", FISH CURRY" etc.

Please Help

Comment: Edit your question and add some sample data, the behavior you’re pursuing and the result. Otherwise is difficult to understand what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VLOOKUP from VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngCell As Range, m, v

    For Each rngCell In Range("A2:A11")
        v = rngCell.Value 
        If Len(v) > 0 Then

            'See if the value is in your lookup table
            m = Application.Vlookup(v, _
                 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Range("A1:B100"), 2, FALSE)  

            'If found a match then replace with the vlookup result
            If Not IsError(m) Then rngCell.Value = m 

        End If    
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a great example. Thanks Tim Williams.